# Where to store secret API keys for cryptocurrency dashboard

Tags: database, api, key, dashboard, cryptocurrency

I want to develop a webapp which is a custom cryptocurrency dashboard for a group of users that have accounts at a cryptocurrency exchange.

The idea is to give users accounts for this webapp with a username and password with which they can log in to view their personal dashboard, once they are logged in, I need to retrieve their current cryptocurrency balance by using their read-only secret API keys to communicate with the cryptocurrency exchange API and retrieve their balance. I am thinking to store these read-only secret keys in some cloud database which links their account to their read-only secret key, so that when the user successfully logs in, I retrieve the secret API key that belongs to that user. Then I want to use that data to create different plots to show on the front-end dashboard.

My question:
Is it bad practice to store these secret API keys in a database like that, even though they are just read-only? If so, what would be a good alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert, but storing them in a table sounds reasonable for me, as long as you secure it correctly.

The one thing that its for sure is that your backed will have to act as a proxy (your FE shouldn't even be aware of the existence of this secret. You also probably will need some sort of checksum mechanism.

I'd guess having a separated service and database with stricter security would be the "most secure option" for this, but it depends on your application.